Write xscale in Myr (not in scientific notation)
I wan't to make a plot where in the xaxis, which in this case is time, appears as tick values Myr. As one can se in this plot:
plot1
But i can only get a plot with scientific notation on the xaxis (that shows a 1e7 at the end of the axis):
plot2
I've tried to activate the 'plain' feature on the xaxis, but it doesn't give the result I want.
Solved...
Yea just needed to add this to my code:
xticks = np.linspace(0,10E6,11)           #valores do eixo x
xlabels = [f'{i}' for i in range(0,11,1)] #etiquetas do eixo x
for i in range(len(axs)): axs[i].set_xticks(xticks,labels=xlabels)

